# Retrieving rendered json from ember .save() method

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

My rails backend renders a json response when I call .save() on my model. When doing a jquery ajax PUT request like this, I can retrieve the data returned (see below, data parameter) :

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'PUT',
    url: '/conversations/' + conversation.id + '/assignation',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: newAssignation,
    success: function(data) {
        conversation.get('content').pushObject(data)};       
});
```

How can I retrieve rendered json when calling .save() method on my model?

```
self.store.find('conversation', conv.id).then(function(conversation){

    conversation.set('status', 'opened');
    conversation.save(); ** This returns json response that I want to retrieve **           

});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `record.save()`, the following things happen (as of Ember Data 1.0.0-beta-19.1):

1. You run [`record.save()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#method_save).
2. The record [tells](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/internal-model.js#L133) the store to schedule its save operation: [`store.scheduleSave()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_scheduleSave).
3. Once per runloop cycle, the store [flushes](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1286) scheduled save operations: [`store.flushPendingSave()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_flushPendingSave).
4. The store [asks](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L2081) the record's adapter to perform the save: [`adapter.updateRecord()`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L559).
5. The adapter [asks](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L579) the record's serializer to convert the record into a JSON payload: [`serializer.serializeIntoHash`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_serializeIntoHash).
6. The adapter [builds](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L582) the URL: [`adapter.buildURL`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_buildURL).
7. The adapter [performs](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest-adapter.js#L584) the request to the backend.
8. The store [asks](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L2096) the serializer to convert the response from the server into data and push it into the store: [`serializer.extract()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extract) -> [`serializer.extractSave()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractSave) -> [`serializer.extractSingle()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractSingle).
9. The serializer [runs](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest-serializer.js#L270) the [`serializer.normalizePayload()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_normalizePayload) which does nothing but you can override it to clean the payload.
10. The serializer [prepares](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest-serializer.js#L273) the payload and [pushes](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest-serializer.js#L309) the resulting payload to the store.
11. The store [runs](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1321) its [`store.didSaveRecord()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_didSaveRecord) method.
12. The store [triggers](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1343) the `didCommit` event on the model.
13. Finally, the promise returned by `record.save()` in item 1 resolves.

Some steps are missing in this list, I only highlighted important ones. I encourage you to follow the whole procedure in the sources, I gave you enough references.

Now to your question. I suggest that you override the [`serializer.extractSave()`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_extractSave) method. There you can convert your backend's payload into the Ember format and fiddle with it. Don't forget to call `this.super()` with all the arguments and the modified payload so that Ember actually pushes it to the store!

Comment: Looks exactly like what I want. What is the correct way to use extractSave() and where to use it? Do I have to overwrite it or is it already implemented? I didn't find any example on this.

Comment: Run `ember g adapter conversation`, it will create a file. In that file, declare an `extractSave` method.

Comment: Because I didn't need to store those datas in a model, I did a simple ember.$.ajax and appended the retrieved payload to what I wanted.